# How do I cause a faded out version of certain lines of code and highlight a few. (See example)

Tags: color, tcolorbox

[image]

I need to know how the first 4 lines of code, are faded, the and how the Ck and Ck' are made with different colors.

It'd be of great help if I could get the code for just saw the first 4-5 lines.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you also want to know how to set the algorithm? How to achieve the alignment on the right? What about the fonts? Could you at least provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to get the community started? Why did you tag this [tag:tcolorbox]?

Comment: You want to use the (xcolor)[http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor] package for the color/shading effects. Please see (this document)[http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf] for a detailed set of instructions. For other issues pointed out in the previous comment, please search for a package for pseudocode. There a few to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=40}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\newcommand\myRed[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-\algorithmicindent}\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\tcbset{
common/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  top=1pt,
  bottom=1pt
  },
blue/.style={
  common,
  colback=LightBlue!90,
  colframe=LightBlue!90,
  highlight math style={colback=LightBlue!50,colframe=Navy,boxsep=0pt}
  },
green/.style={
  common,
  colback=Green!50,
  colframe=Green!50,
  highlight math style={colback=Green!50,colframe=Green}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\uncover<2>{\If{$quality\ge 9$}}
\uncover<2>{\State $a\gets perfect$}
\uncover<2>{\ElsIf{$quality\ge 7$}}
\uncover<2>{\State $a\gets good$}
\ElsIf{\tcbhighmath[blue]{k\ge 5}}
\State \myRed{$c_k$} $a\gets medium$
\ElsIf{$quality\ge 3$}
\State\myRed{$c'_k$} \tcbhighmath[green]{a\gets bad}
\Else
\State $a\gets unusable$
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Some comments:

1. The transparent effect cab be achieved using `\uncover` and something like

   ```
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=40}
   ```
2. The highlighted parts can be easily achieved using `\tcbhighmath` from the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package.
3. The algorithm was typeset using `algpseudocode`, a part of the [`algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) bundle.